# javascript button which stops the image loading process

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a javascript (or jQuery if that's a possibility) button for my HP which stops the loading of the images on the page (for example when a user has to pay per MB and is only interested in the text).

I searched and searched and found answers like "remove the src", or "use window.stop()", but the problem is that they don't work, cancel the whole loading process, or simply don't do what I had in mind (like removing the images completely).

Does anyone know how I could achieve that?
Thank you very much :)

PS.: found a how to that claims that it can stop the download of specific parts of the site, but it doesn't really explain how to specify the part. I don't get how to link things here so here's the url: http://www.ehow.com/how_6104889_kill-browser-downloads-javascript.html

Thanks again.

Comment: Do you want to stop the displaying or the downloading?

Comment: Oh, it automatically made a link out of it. Yay :)

Comment: I want to stop the download after the request was made

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: don't bother. If a user has such limited bandwidth that loading images is a problem, they will have disabled images anyway, or they will use some mechanism to load images on demand. You don't want to burden users with a non-standard solution that only works on your homepage. Simply put, it is not your problem.

Long answer: you can use placeholders instead of actual images on the initial page load, and then use Javascript to set the `src` attributes one by one, having each successful load trigger the next image. You will lose parallel loading though, which means you are punishing high-bandwidth users (which is the overwhelming majority these days) with much longer loading times, and you'll be spending a lot of effort on a feature that is (see short version) mostly useless.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but it's like expecting people not to use IE. I mean, you can, but they won't stop. Also, I want to add the button to a Joomla! module, so changing the HTML is no option. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's actually the reverse of trying to stop people from using IE. If they don't want images, they'll just disable them; there is no need to do anything about it yourself. This is unlike IE, where people complain that your perfectly standards-compliant web site is 'broken', when really the browser is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change src to point to an empty image.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem is that I read that the image keeps on loading (for the cache) if you break the src because the request was already send. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to cancel the image loading process programmatically from within the web page.

You could try breaking all image `src`s using JavaScript but it's a dirty approach, and your results may vary - it could be that the browser continues to load the resource nevertheless.

The best way to go would probably be either loading images *on demand* (which is possible to do from within the page), or offer the option of serving pages from server side that don't contain the images in the first place.

However, as @tdammers correctly points out in his answer, it's probably best not to bother. People on a traffic quota will take their own precautions against loading too much content.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem is that I read that the image keeps on loading (for the cache) if you break the src because the request was already send. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lucas yeah - I don't think there is a way to do that then.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother replicating a browser configuration option with an in-page button, but I would recommend showing a placeholder image then lazy-loading the images for mobile users.

Also as you like JQuery, there are jQuery Lazy-Loading plugins out there.